# When to Denormalize a Database Design

Tags: sql, database-design, database-normalization, denormalization

I know that normalization has been extensively discussed on Stack Overflow. I've read many of the previous discussions. I've got some additional questions though.

I'm working on a legacy system with at least 100 tables. The database is has some un-normalized structure, tables that contain a variety of disparate data, and other problems. I've been given the task of trying to improve it. I can't just start again but need to modify the existing schema.

In the past I have always tried to design normalized databases. Now the questions. A senior developer has suggested that in some cases we can't normalize:

1. With temporal data. For example an invoice is created that links to a product. If a customer asks for a copy of this invoice a year later we must be able to produce an exact copy of the original. What if the product price, name or description have been updated? The senior guy suggested that the price and other product information should be copied to the invoice table. I'm thinking maybe we should have another table such as productPrice that has a date field so we can track changes in price over time. We would need the same thing for the product description and name I guess? Seems complicated. What do you think?
2. The database is an accounting system. I'm not very familiar with accounting. At the moment some summary data is derived and stored in the database. For example total sales for the year. My senior associate has said that accountants like to check things are correct by comparing this value with data that is actually calculated from invoices etc to give them confidence that the application is working correctly.

He said that at the moment for example we can tell if someone deleted an invoice from last year mistakenly because the totals will not be the same. He also pointed out that it could be quite slow to calculate these totals on the fly. Of course I said that data should not be duplicated and should always be calculated when needed. I suggested that we could use SQL Reporting Services or some other solution that will generate these reports overnight and cache them. Anyway he's not convinced. Any comments on this?

Comment: Reporting Services is a perfectly good solution for the summary report cacheing problem. That's what SSRS was designed for.

Comment: You might want to ask the details about 2) point under a different question. Normalization is complicated enough. And then you need to define it a bit better, for example - you claim that he claims that it could be slow, but at the same time that he would use it to check if someone deleted something (and you provide that as an example for application working correctly - and unless you mean that security is implemented correctly, then your example actually assumes that application is working correctly). So, as I said - better make that point 2 a bit more clear and less self-contradicting.

Comment: Neither of these are denormalization. If you look at the desired desgns, they don't normalize to the multi-table so-called normalized design, they are already normalized. The multi-table so-called normalized designs are the result of normalizing designs with the same columns but different table meanings & dependencies. PS And I see nvogel's answer says this.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your senior colleague is a developer, not a data modeller. You are better off starting from scratch, without them. Normalisation is complicated only to those who will not read books. It is fair enough that he makes you think, but some of the issues are absurd.

Your numbers:

1. You need to appreciate the differences between actual online data, and historic data; then the difference between merely historic and archival needs.  All of them are right for the specific business requirement, and wrong for all others, there is no universal right and wrong.

   - why is there no paper-based copy of the invoice ?  In most countries that would be a legal and tax requirement, what exactly is the difficulty of fishing out the old invoice ?
   - where the database has the *requirement* of storing the closed invoices, then sure, as soon as the invoice is closed, you need a method of capturing that information.
   - `ProductPrice` (actually, I would call it `ProductDate`) is a good idea, but may not be necessary. But you are right, you need to evaluate the currency of data, in the full context of the whole database.
   - I cannot see how copying the product price to the invoice table would help (are not there many line items ?)
   - in modern databases, where the *copy* of the invoice is required to be regurgitated, the closed Invoice is additionally stored in a different form, eg XML. One customer saves the PDFs as BLOBs. So there is no messing around with what the product price was five years ago.  But the basic invoice data is online and current, even for closed invoices; you just cannot recalculate ancient invoice using current prices.
   - some people use an archive_invoice table, but that has problems because now every code segment or user report tool has to look in two places (note that these days some users understand databases better than most developers)

- Anyway, that is all discussion, for your understanding.  Now for the technical intent.

  - The database serves current and archival purposes from the one set of tables (no "archive" tables
  - Once an Invoice is created, it is a legal document, and cannot be changed or deleted (it can be reversed or partially credited by a new Invoice, with negative values).  They are marked `IsIssued/IsPaid/Etc`
  - `Products` cannot be deleted, they can be marked `IsObsolete`
  - There are separate tables for InvoiceHeader and InvoiceItem
  - `InvoiceItem` has FKs to both `InvoiceHeader` and `Product`
  - for many reasons (not only those you mention), the InvoiceItem row contains the `NumUnits; ProductPrice; TaxAmount; ExtendedPrice`.  Sure, this looks like a "denormalisation" but it is not, because prices, taxation rates, etc, are subject to change.  But more important, the legal requirement is that we can reproduce the old invoice on demand.
  - (where it can be reproduced from paper files, this is not required)
  - the `InvoiceTotalAmount` is a derived column, just `SUM()` of the InvoiceItems

2. That is rubbish.  Accounting systems, and accountants do not "work" like that.

   - If it is a true accounting system, then it will have JournalEntries, or "double entry"; that is what a qualified account is required to use (by law).
   - **Double Entry Accounting** does not mean duplicate entries; it means every financial transaction (one amount) shall have a source account and target account that it is applied to; so there is no "denormalisation" or duplication.  In a banking database, because the financial transactions are against single accounts, that is commonly rendered as two separate financial transactions (rows) within one Db Transaction.  Ordinary commercial database constraints are used to ensure that there are two "sides" to every financial transaction.
   - Ensuring that Invoices are not deleteable is a separate issue, to do with security, etc.  if anyone is paranoid about things being deleted from their database, **and** their database was not secured by a qualified person, then they have more and different problems that have nothing to do with this question.  Obtain a security audit, and do whatever they tell you.
   - Wikipedia is not a reliable source of information about any technical subject, let alone Normalisation.
   - **A Normalised database is always much faster than Un-Normalised database**
     So it is very important to understand what Normalisation and Denormalisaion is, and what it isn't.  The process is greatly hindered when people have fluid and amateur "definitions", it just leads to confusion and time-wasting "discussions".  When you have fixed definitions, you can avoid all that, and just get on with the job.
   - **Summary tables** are quite normal, to save the time and processing power, of recalculating info that does not change, eg: YTD totals for every year but this year; MTD totals for every month in this year but not this month. "Always recalculating" data is a bit silly when (a) the info is very large and (b) does not change.  Calculate for the current month only

     - In banking systems (millions of Trades per day), at EndOfDay, we calculate and store Daily Total as well.  These are overwritten for the last five days, because Auditors are making changes, and JournalEntries against financial transactions for the last 5 days are allowed.
     - non-banking systems generally do not need daily totals
   - Summary tables are not a "denormalisation" (except in the eyes of those who have just learned about "normalisation" from their magical, ever-changing fluid "source"; or as non-practitioners, who apply simple black-or-white rules to everything).  Again, the definition is not being argued here; it simply *does not apply* to Summary tables.
   - Summary tables do not affect data integrity (assuming of course that the data that they were sourced from was integral).
   - Summary tables are an **addition** to the *current* data, which are not required to have the same constraints as the *current* data.  There are essentially reporting tables or data warehouse tables, as opposed to *current* data tables.
   - There are **no Update Anomalies** (which is a strict definition) related to Summary tables.  You cannot change or delete an invoice from last year.  Update Anomalies apply to true Denormalised or Un-Normalised *current* data.

---

### Response to Comments

> *so its ok to do denormalisation for the sakes of archiving right?*

My explanation above appears not to be clear enough.  Let's look at an example, and compare the options.

[image: Foo]

[image: Foo]

[image: Foo]

So, no.  Archiving is a hideous option (I have corrected thousands of archived tables back to their home; corrected the indices, and restored normal performance, as well as returning the `SELECT` to query just one table instead of two).  But if you do archive, it is not denormalised, it is worse, a **copy**.

[image: Foo]

The best option by far.  Again, this is the simple version, the full version requires an understanding of the temporal definition in Codd's *Relational Model* (not the ever-changing nonsense marketed by the detractors), and an SQL-compliant platform.

---

> *I disagree strongly with the statement that "A Normalised database is always much faster than Unnormalised database". That is patently false even if I don't harp on the use of "always". There are many scenarios in which selective, coherent denormalization of a database can result in extreme performance improvement.*

> *Example [of justified De-Normalisation]: a complex join for a date-limited data set, like a month-end summary for a complex business. If the data is collected over the course of a month; then forever stable; and queried often — it can make sense to pre-compute via a materialized view, trigger, or more sophisticated method.*

Evidently we need clear definitions.

- **Normalisation**

  - **Purpose**
    to eliminate (not merely reduce) duplicate data
    Note that there are no complex joins, just ordinary simple joins.
  - **Method**
    Formal Relational data modelling
    (not stepping through the NFs by number).
- **Un-Normalised**
  Failure to Normalise properly, leaving Update Anomalies in the database, and makes a mess of the Transactions
- **De-Normalised**
  After formal Normalisation, one or more columns *additionally* placed in chosen tables, for performance reasons.

  - Eg. the pretend "SQL" does not perform the normal query with acceptable speed.
  - Note that, over a period of 40 years of replacing poor databases,  all databases that were declared to be De-normalised have in fact been Un-Normalised.
- **Summary Table/Materialised View**
  As detailed above in the Answer (please read again), and as illustrated in the graphic **Current Only**, it is an *additional* table to serve the purpose of providing summary values for history, that does not change.  This is common.

  - There is no column that is duplicated, it cannot be categorised as "De-Normalisation".

You were not in disagreement with my statement [A Normalised database is always much faster than Unnormalised database], which relates to Normalised vs Un-Normalised, you were categorising the summary table incorrectly, as "de-Normalised".

---

> *If you can know in advance what complex, time-consuming queries a database will receive, you can precompute the results of those queries -- for example, replacing a 14-table join with a table that already contains the needed data.*

That is different again.  The two common reasons for that are:

1. the database isn't Normalised in the first place, so queries on large tables are slow

   - the proper cure is to Normalise properly
2. your pretend "SQL" is so slow

   - the proper cure for that is to obtain a genuine SQL Platform.

Such that you need to build an *additional* file (or Materialised View) to service the slow queries.  Yes, that is de-Normalising, and on a grand scale, but it is worse, it is a 100% **copy** of those fields.

Comment: Generally your whole answer is very good and very useful; there are a few sections which are disputable, but there is one that is completely useless and mostly wrong. This is a section about wiki - the amount of contradictions you managed to pack in there is quite interesting - I'll just single out one argument: "*Their 'knowledge' comes from reading and not qualification.*". It shows that you would use reading as an argument for inferior knowledge. (!) (I will not defend wiki in detail; it is useful for certain purposes and it can be substandard for other; as long as it quotes references...

Comment: ..and does not omit major areas of a concept, it is mostly *useful*). You wrongly generalize regarding authors and the process. You wrongly generalize about people who quote wikipedia - for example I quote wikipedia because it is available to everyone, not because it was the primary source of my knowledge; I also quote it because it usually refers to other works, so it is easy to trace claims. Also, I try to assess what wikipedia quote and the general quality. I hope these remarks will help you see and correct subjectivity that you employed on that point.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA, 'technical' basis in this case is pure logic. You wrongly generalize: "There are a few people on this site who think wiki is a place that you can learn something. It isn't." This 'conclusion' has no merit in logic, it is an opinion. One that I can attempt(!) to disprove like this: 1) read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem 2) if you accept the references and quality of that article you would learn something* and that would contradict your own statement. * = argumentum ad hominem is logical (and rhetorical) *fallacy*(!) - which has no place in technical discussions.

Comment: Most of this answer is helpful, but I disagree strongly with the statement that "A Normalised database is always much faster than Unnormalised database".  That is patently false even if I don't harp on the use of "always".  There are many scenarios in which selective, coherent denormalization of a database can result in extreme performance improvement.  If you can know in advance what complex, time-consuming queries a database will receive, you can precompute the results of those queries -- for example, replacing a 14-table join with a table that already contains the needed data.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson  1) If you ever have a genuine example where the Science is "patently false" and the mythology is somehow "true", please post, and I will answer.  Or even "coherent denormalisation".  2) _replacing a 14-table join with a table_: you do not appear to understand that you have implemented a View (14-table Join) as a table, nor the horrendous consequences.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA Example: a complex join for a date-limited data set, like a month-end summary for a complex business. If the data is collected over the course of a month; then forever stable; and queried often — it can make sense to pre-compute via a materialized view, trigger, or more sophisticated method. The choice to coherently denorm or not can be made based on access patterns and performance requirements. Why would a _coherent_ denorm be controversial? Not a sloppy design - a considered decision to precompute data to meet the performance requirements of a specific system.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson  I have added a section to the Answer, to provide a full response to your points & questions, which cannot be done in comments.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA You mention that invoices `are marked IsIssued/IsPaid/Etc`. Specifically for `isPaid`, would that information be _stored_ in its own column or would it be _derived_ from checking if the sum of the invoice line items equals the sum of the payments applied to the invoice? Similarly, what about the `InvoiceAmount` and `PaymentAmount` columns from your example: would those values stored or would they be derived in the specific domain of invoicing?

Comment: @sawprogramming 1) `IsPaid` (It is a simple example.)  If the determination of "paid in full" is straight-forward, can be derived easily, one does not need an additional indicator.  If not, one does.  Refer to the discussion in [**this Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688982/derived-account-balance-vs-stored-account-balance-for-a-simple-bank-account/29713230#29713230). 2) Generally, if the `InvoiceAmount` is easily derived (sum of line items), do not store it. 3) `PaymentAmount` is different, it allows partial payment, so it has to be stored.

Comment: Having an archive of price is not denormalized because they do not represent the same metaphysical entity. They are entirely distinct concepts, and there is no reason why someone would confuse one for the other. Representing price history is a nice design, but having a table for current history and other tables that are snapshots of historical information is not wrong.

Comment: @JustinMeiners  1) Not sure what `current history` means.  2) If any data is duplicated, it is un-normalised, it is wrong, it causes an Update Anomaly.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA 1). The current state, as opposed to historical values. 2) If any two fields happen to have an equivalent value like "2", does that mean that's wrong?  I think that's absurd, and is essentially what's going on in having a historical snapshot and a current value (distinct concepts) that happen to initially share a value.

Comment: @JustinMeiners 2) I did not say that, you did.  I cannot defend what I did not say.  Yes, what you said is absurd, it has nothing to do with the Answer.  I gave Normalisation rules.  In that context (not yours), if any datum is duplicated, it is Un-normalised. You are arguing from ignorance, and refusal accept Normalisation rules.  1) if the `current state` is duplicated elsewhere it creates an **Update Anomaly**, because it breaks Normalisation.  3) an SQL implementation is physical, hopefully following Logic, which is the intellectual understanding, there is nothing "metaphysical" about it.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA you did not respond to the point I brought up, and are misinterpreting me. you claim the datum is duplicated. Why? You seem to agree with me it's not because their values are the same. So, is it because they represent the same logical piece of information? I argue they do not. Can you explain why a snapshot  of a prior state in time and a current state are duplicate pieces of information?

Comment: @JustinMeiners 1) I was trying to understand you, but I cannot.  Sorry.  2) I have provided a full Answer, complete with definitions.  You are trying to make something that fails, to succeed, by twisting the definitions.  No.  It is you misrepresenting the definitions, and my responses.  Enough.  Comments are not suitable for arguments.  Why don't you provide an Answer with your own definitions, in which what fails in reality, succeeds. With example data  3) Science is about objective truth, it cares not who agrees/disagrees, or about citations, or consensus.

Comment: @JustinMeiners 4) Even your own sentence *a snapshot of a prior state in time [of a datum] and a current state [of that datum] are duplicate pieces of information* contains the seed of why it is a duplicate, but you are not getting it.  There are two places for that one datum, a gross Normalisation error.  When conforming to rules, one can write a database that stores that **one datum is one place**, such that the datum is **either** in current **xor** in history, **not both**.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA  "I was trying to understand you, but I cannot". I don't think this is going anywhere. Have a good day.

Answer (score 13):

1) This is an archive. Everything that is in it should never be updated. I'd go with the senior guy's suggestion and have that invoice table be self-contained. Perhaps use a blob for the invoice itself that contains markup language?

2) Reporting services, a warehouse table that is trigger-updated, something you build by script whenever... these would all be fine, I think. It is indeed ideal to be normalized, but it isn't always fast. I have a good sized healthcare database I manage which is fully normalized... and then has a series of de-normalized tables with rolled-up equations and commonly pulled fields. Almost everything runs from that de-normalized set -- it's just faster to append to these with a trigger when files are loaded than to keep having to pull from various tables everytime I want to look at a 100,000 record report.

Comment: Great comment Autocracy - thanks! 1) So the invoice table would not have a relation with the products table? Is that what you mean? 2) If the totals are updated with a trigger wouldn't that make any insert that fires the trigger very slow? Sorry but I'm pretty ignorant of this approach. Cheers, Mark.

Comment: You _could_ add a version dimension to the product table and make it insert-only and then reference unique rpoduct version in the invoices. Conceptually this is the cleanest design, however, even if I was designing a brand new system I'd hesitate to use this design because of the extra complexity in the rest of the system - it's just not worth it. Let alone trying to add this to a legacy app =)

Comment: 1) Serguei says it well, but yes... the invoice table would not have a relation to the products table. 2) Triggers that update things on insert do result in (for my case, only slightly) slower inserts, but most of my workloads are very read-heavy. You could batch this process to run overnight, hourly, weekly... whatever. Clean base copy, duplicated roll-up that makes things faster. Time / space trade-off.

Answer (score 8):

You raise valid points, however you are not completely clear on normalization and what it means, for example in

1) The claim that keeping the invoices as they were denormalizes the data is completely and totally wrong.
Let's take price for example - if you have a business requirement that states that you have to keep history of prices then keeping only current price is wrong and it breaks the requirements. And it has nothing to do with normalization, it's simply not designed well. Denormalization is about introducing possibilities for ambiguity into your model (and other artifacts) - and in this case you are simply not modelling your problem space properly.
There is nothing wrong in modelling your database to support temporal data (or versioning and/or separating the areas of the database into archive/temporal and the working set).

Looking at normalization without looking at semantics (in terms of requirements) is not possible.

Also, if your senior developer can't see the difference then I guess he didn't get his seniority in RDBMS development ;)

2) Second part is indeed denormalization. However, if you ever run across senior DB analyst who seriously preaches normalization, you will hear him/her say that it is perfectly acceptable to denormalize as long as you do it consciously and ensure that benefits overweight deficiencies and that anomalies will not bite you. They will also tell you to normalize the logical model and that in the physical model you are allowed to deviate from the ideal for various purposes (performance, maintenance, etc...). In my book the main purpose of normalisation is so that you don't have hidden anomalies (see this article on [5NF](http://www.dataqualitypro.com/data-quality-home/5th-normal-form-the-achilles-heel-of-etl-data-warehouse-proj.html) for example)

The caching of intermediate results is allowed even on normalized databases and even by biggest evangelists of normalization - you can do it at application layer (as some sort of cache) or you can do it at the database level or you can have a data warehouse for such purposes. These are all valid choices and have nothing to do with normalizing the logical model.

Also, as for your accountant - you should be able to convince him that what he is claiming is *not* a good test and develop a set of tests (maybe together with him) that will automate the testing of the system without users intervention and give you higher confidence that your system is bug free.

On the other hand I know of systems that require users to enter duplicate information, such as to enter the number of lines on the invoice before or after entering actual lines, to insure that the entry is complete. This data is 'duplicated' and you don't have to store it if you have a procedure that will validate the input. If that procedure comes later it is allowed to store the 'denormalized' data - again, the semantics justify it and you can look at the model as normalized. (it is beneficial to wrap your head around this concept)

**EDIT:**
The term "denormalized" in (2) is not correct if you look at the formal definition of normal forms and if you consider a design denormalized if it breaks any of the normal forms (to some people this is obvious and there is no other way about it).

Still, you might want to get used to the idea that a lot of people and not necessary useless texts will use the term normalization for any effort that tries to reduce redundancy in the database (just as an example, you will find scientific papers, by which I don't say that they must be right, just as a warning that it is common, that call derived attributes a form of denormalization, see [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6V8S-4F973FJ-1&_user=10&_coverDate=10%2F31%2F2006&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1563563163&_rerunOrigin=scholar.google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=920a202d613caf747ba4b1927fd631b8&searchtype=a)).

If you want to refer to some more coherent and recognized authorities (again, not recognized by all), maybe the words of C.J.Date can make a clear distinction:

> Much of design theory has to do with
>   reducing redundancy; normalization
>   reduces redundancy within relvars,
>   orthogonality reduces it across
>   relvars.

qouted from [Database in depth: relational theory for practitioners](http://books.google.com/books?id=FU7uuHc3oNcC&lpg=PA151&ots=Rr_7_3VEMt&dq=Update%20Anomaly%20c.j.date&pg=PA158#v=onepage&q=Update%20Anomalies&f=false)

and on the next page

> just as a failure to normalize all the
>   way implies redundancy and can lead to
>   certain anomalies, so too can a
>   failure to adhere to orthogonality.

So, the proper term for redundancy across relvars is orthogonality (basically all normal forms talk about single relvar so if you look strictly at normalization it would never suggest any improvements due to dependencies between two different relvars).

Anyway, one of the other important concepts when you consider database design is also a difference between logical and physical database models. A lot of things that are useful on physical level, such as tables with subtotals or indexes have no place in the logical model - where you try to establish and investigate relationships between the concepts you are trying to model. And that's why you can say they are permissible and they don't ruin the design.

Lines sometimes can be a bit blurry on what is logical model and what is physical model. Especially good example is a table with subtotals. To consider it part of physical implementation and ignore it on the logical level you have to:

- ensure that users (and applications) can not update the subtotal table directly in a manner that is not consistent with their predicate (in another words have a bug in the subtotalling procedure)
- ensure that users (and applications) can not update the table on which these are dependent without updating the subtotal (in another words that some application will not delete a row from the detail table without updating the total)

If you break any of the above rules you will end up with *inconsistent database* which will provide *inconsistent facts*. (In such case if you want to formally design a procedure for fixing or examining the problems caused, you would not consider it just an additional table, it would exist at the logical level; where it should not be).

Also, the normalisation always depends on the semantics and the business rules you are trying to model. For example DBAPerformance gives an example in which storing the `TaxAmount` in the transaction table is not denormalized design, but he fails to mention that it depends what kind of system you are trying to model (is that obvious?); for example if the transaction has another attribute called `TaxRate` it will usually be denormalized because there is functional dependency on a set of non-key attributes (TaxAmount = Amount * TaxRate => FD: Amount,TaxRate -> TaxAmount), and one of these should be removed or guaranteed to be consistent.

Obviously, you might say, but, if the system you are building is for an audit company, then you might not have functional dependency - they might be auditing someone who is using manual calculations or has faulty software or must have ability to record incomplete data and the calculation might be wrong originally and as audit company you must record the fact as it happened.

So, semantics (predicates) which are determined by requirements will influence if any of the normal forms are broken - by influencing functional dependencies (in another words correctly establishing functional dependencies is quite important part of modelling when you strive for normalized database).

Comment: @PerformanceDBA re 1) I am *adding* to your answer by mentioning that semantics influence FDs, which influence conformance to NFs. Again, you have not talked about this. Your claim that I have reading problems is not related to the quoted text 2) The provided example shows how 3NF can be broken or be satisfied depending on the semantics of an attribute. This is flatly correct. See details above.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA, are you really aware that argumentum ad hominem is logical fallacy? Of course it is possible to add to each other's answers, it is actually preferred to repeating stuff and differential views on a subject are useful. If I say 'if your senior developer can't see the difference then I guess he didn't get his seniority in RDBMS development' and you later say 'Your senior colleague is a developer, not a data modeller' then you are adding to/refining something that has already been said. It is possible for others to do the same and be right (even accidentally).

Comment: I've read ur point in (1) multiple times, pardon my english, it means you support that we should store the exact `price` in the invoice table for the sakes of `history` or `archiving`, right?

Answer (score 5):

I agree with your senior about (1). A transaction table row must capture the entire state at the moment of the transaction. Period. What you're suggesting doesn't record the actual data, so it's inadmissible. I also agree about (2). Whatever the business wants by way of crosschecking, you must implement. Accounting is based on cross checking, double entry, rolling up ledgers, etc. You must do it. This so fundamental that you shouldn't even look on it as denormalization, just as implementing the business requirement.

Comment: double entry book keeping is not denormalized (don't let double mislead you - it only states that for each transaction you need to have two accounts, so it is about referential integrity of data and not denormalization of data). As for crosschecking and rolling up - that's a better example. Still Mark's main problem is that he is not separating logical from physical design, see my answer.

Comment: I didn't say it *was* denormalized, did I?

Answer (score 5):

1) Does not require denormalization. You just need to determine what level of detail of each change you need and persist that with an appropriate key.

2) Has nothing to do with denormalization. Storing summary data does not make the database denormalized. Storing results derived from non key attributes *in the same table* would be an example of denormalization but that doesn't seem to be what you are talking about here.

Comment: @dportas, well actually 2) can be considered denormalized - it can allow for all modification anomalies to occur (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Free_the_database_of_modification_anomalies).

Comment: @Unreason.  David is right.  Wiki is a cesspool, not worth discussing what it says today.  Summary tables are **additional** tables for speed; they are not part of the Normalised db.  There is no update anomaly for last years invoice total (there is for todays, and that should not be summarised).  5NF is, by definition, regardless of what wiki says this week, zero update anomalies.  They are still figuring out the "definition of update anomaly.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA - it's not from this week, the definition of the modification anomalies are from Codd (Further Normalization of the Data Base Relational Model. IBM Research Report, San Jose, California RJ909: (1971)).

Comment: @PerformanceDBA - also if I may be a bit cheeky, I especially agree with your argument that these additional tables are not part of the normalised db. They are part of denormalised db. Which was my point. :D (if I want to be completely precise I would say that they are denormalised if there is no guarantee at DBA level, such as triggers, that the values in 2 tables are going to be consistent at all times).

Comment: @Unreason. One of the goals of normalization is to remove data modification anomalies but that doesn't mean a normalized schema is entirely free of them. A 5NF schema can still have redundancy due to the same data being duplicated in different relations. So it's not accurate to say that a summary table is automatically denormalized, redundant or not.

Comment: @dportas, I guess it depends on the usage of word denormalised - if you mean 'breaking any of 1NF-6NF' then you are right. If you use it to denote *existence* of update anomalies then I am right (most of the times, I sometimes use it in the other sense too :D ).

Comment: @Unreason. At the very least the term "denormalized" implies that there is some corresponding Normal Form that removes the anomaly. If there isn't then what's the point of calling it "denormalized"? Almost any non-trivial database schema will include redundancy and therefore anomalies of some description. In fact I would challenge anyone to come up with a really useful database design that allowed no data modification anomalies at all. By your definition pretty much every database would be "denormalized" and therefore it would hardly be worth using the word at all.

Comment: @dportas, no, as I said before - E.F.Codd's definition from 1970, denormalization refers to - '1. To free the collection of relations from undesirable insertion, update and deletion dependencies; 2...' (see previous link). This definition, made was made more than 40 years ago, *BEFORE* some of the higher normal forms were defined (as a blueprint for them). Therefore it is permissible to use the term in that way. As for every database breaking it - no; depending on the semantics of your model, you can indeed have a database (especially logical model) with no undesirable update dependencies.

Comment: You are quoting out of context. Those are Codd's remarks about Normalization but they are not a definition of Denormalization. I'd be interested to see examples of a non-trivial database with no update anomalies. I dare say it is just about possible but as far as I know it's impossible to prove because there is no formal way to identify redundancy. Date/McGoveran came up with a classic example. A pair of relations called Loves and Hates. They are "normalized" (6NF) but also have the potential for data modification anomalies because they are mutually exlusive.

Answer (score 5):

Your senior developer makes extremely valid points.  I've learned these the hard way myself by servicing systems that don't de-normalize the historical data.

In a sense it's not really adding any overhead to the database.  You are creating invoice tables from existing data in the database.  An invoice is a snapshot in time.  De-normalizing the information you need to produce that invoice can make your reporting SO much easier.  When you are required to produce a new report and expected to do it quickly you will appreciate the de-normalization.

In terms of having total in the database.  This has saved my ass before when I've made a change to an application that caused numbers not to add up the same way (not as hard as you may think).  On a live application the totals gave me a definite place to return to in order correct the discrepancies.  I've written about this before, you can read it here: http://jlrand.com/?p=95

Answer (score 1):

For #1

The invoice should be calculated from the sales and payments.  If you do not have detailed sales data including price/product/discount/shipping/etc start there.

For #2

Writing an accounting system into the db from scratch is a big project.  Make sure you have the accountants give you business rules so you can measure your systems accuracy.  The last thing you want is the CFO step into the DBA meeting and announce the DB is overcharging the customer, even worse you are undercharging and driving the company out of business.

If you have SQL Server give the Adventure Works db a look.  If you hate MS then look at Adventure Works and don't do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Database normalization removes duplicates and makes sql queries for data update more efficient (and gives some other improvements).

But if most of your queries are used for data selecting and select queries connect to several tables at the time, you may consider denormalization of these tables. It will increase the amount of disk space needed for data, time execution of sql update queries but will improve select queries.

Comment: Yes I understand that normalisation helps maintain data integrity for a transactional database (inserts, updates, deletes) but is not so appropriate for a data warehouse that is only subject to selects.

Comment: "[Denormalization] will increase ... time execution of sql update queries" - in general that's not true. If the foreign table is often modified (i.e. exclusive locks are issued) this will slow update/insert queries on the referencing table since these queries will also require read locks on the foreign table (to check constraints).

Comment: @Serguei, denormalization can refer to grouping and to adding redundant data. Redundant data is for speeding up selects (such as subtotals, etc) - and needs to be maintained. In such cases it indeed slows up all updates (insert, updates, deletes). What you refer to, probably, is simple denormalization that groups tables (especially one to one tables) - in this case, on modern systems you can have better overall performance for both selects and updates at the risk of dirty design and crippling your ability to do integrity checks. Which is a no issue if you can guarantee the integrity of data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you are considering rather or not you should create a data warehouse. You should never denormalize your database for historical reporting purposes. Creating an archive and storing your information into your data warehouse will do both: denormalize most of the information and maintain your data history.