# How do I select distinct values from multiple mysql columns and put them in one PHP array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table for songs, where each song can have up to 3 different genres. So in my table, for each song I have column genre1, genre2, and genre3. I'm trying to display all the genres available in a list.

Here's a random example set:

```
genre1    genre2    genre3
metal     jazz
metal     country   pop
oldies    metal
rap
jazz      hip-hop   choir
choir     metal     jazz
```

I want the list, done in php, to display in alphabetical order the available distinct genres to choose from. So it should list this:

- Choir
- Country
- Hip-hop
- Jazz
- Metal
- Oldies
- Pop
- Rap

All help is appreciated. Perhaps I'm not going about this the smartest way, but I couldn't think of a better way.

Comment: What does the data look like when they come in from MySql? Is it an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the separate columns don't make a difference? If that is the case you can use a `UNION`

```
SELECT genre1 AS g FROM t UNION SELECT genre2 AS g FROM t UNION SELECT genre3 AS g FROM t
```

If you have a `WHERE` clause, then you will need to copy it 3 times, or use an intermediate *temporary* table

Good luck!

---

table:

```
mysql> SELECT genre1, genre2, genre3 FROM music;
+--------+---------+--------+
| genre1 | genre2  | genre3 |
+--------+---------+--------+
| metal  | jazz    |        | 
| metal  | country | pop    | 
| oldies | metal   |        | 
| rap    |         |        | 
| jazz   | hip-hop | choir  | 
| choir  | metal   | jazz   | 
+--------+---------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

grouping:

```
mysql> SELECT genre1 AS g FROM music UNION ALL
          SELECT genre2 AS g FROM music UNION ALL
          SELECT genre3 AS g FROM music
+---------+
| g       |
+---------+
| metal   | 
| metal   | 
| oldies  | 
| rap     | 
| jazz    | 
| choir   | 
| jazz    | 
| country | 
| metal   | 
|         | 
| hip-hop | 
| metal   | 
|         | 
| pop     | 
|         | 
|         | 
| choir   | 
| jazz    | 
+---------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

count:

```
mysql> SELECT g, COUNT(*) AS c FROM
             (SELECT genre1 AS g FROM music UNION ALL
              SELECT genre2 AS g FROM music UNION ALL
              SELECT genre3 AS g FROM music)
       AS tg GROUP BY g;
+---------+---+
| g       | c |
+---------+---+
|         | 4 | 
| choir   | 2 | 
| country | 1 | 
| hip-hop | 1 | 
| jazz    | 3 | 
| metal   | 4 | 
| oldies  | 1 | 
| pop     | 1 | 
| rap     | 1 | 
+---------+---+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: For convenience you may use `UNION ALL` (which is faster) then do a `SELECT g, COUNT(*) as c FROM (` union here `) AS threeg GROUP BY g`. That will also give you a count, and you can present users with which genres you have more of.

Comment: So when I fetch the array, all of the values will be in $row['g], correct? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quire sure I understand completely the UNION ALL version. Where would I put the UNION ALL? I'm not quire sure of the order. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you have lots of rows, it is worth checking to make sure you have an index on each of the columns. I believe a separate index on genre1, one on genre2, and one on genre3 would be the most efficient way.

Comment: I am also not positive, but if you can add distinct or a group by g for each inner select in the union all, it would make less work combining later. If you don't want the counts, drop the ', count(*) as c' from the select. Then you will only have the 'g' column.

Comment: @user371699 I've modified my post to show the use of UNION ALL. Also TheJacobTaylor is right. Make sure you index your table properly. And as Jon has mentioned below - database design is important. Design it while thinking "how will I use this later" not "what's the easiest way to store data"

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT genre1, genre2, genre3 FROM table
```

Assuming that this comes back as an array of arrays, then:

```
function coalesce_into_array($aggregate, $row) {
    foreach ($row as $genre) {
        $aggregate[] = $genre;
    }

    return $aggregate;
}

$data = array_unique(array_reduce($data, 'coalesce_into_array', array()));
sort($data);
```

However, I would not recommend this in a serious application. The database design is bad. Read about database normalization to find out how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've [denormalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301089/when-to-denormalize-a-database-design)) genres into the three columns for performance reasons, there should be a separate table relating songs and genres:

```
CREATE TABLE SongGenres (
    song INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Songs (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    genre VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX (song, genre),
    INDEX genres (genre) -- improves performance for getting genre names
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

This does away with the requirement for ("Cross Road Blues" can be filed under "Blues" and "Delta Blues", but that's about it) and artificial limitation of (A3's country acid house gospel comes to mind) three genres per song. If you have a limited set of genres, you might want to make the genre column [enumerated](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/enum.html). The SongGenres table simplifies getting all genres:

```
SELECT UNIQUE genre FROM SongGenres;
```

Alternatively, you could normalize further and create a separate table for genres:

```
CREATE TABLE Genres (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX (name)
) Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE SongGenres (
    song INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Songs (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    genre INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Genres (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    UNIQUE INDEX (song, genre)
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

which simplifies getting all genre names even more (though this is only a secondary advantage):

```
SELECT name FROM Genres;
```

A primary advantage to a Genres table is data correctness: if someone misspells a genre, it won't be found in the Genres table. A potential disadvantage is that it limits the valid genres to those in the table. Of course, it makes sense to give the user accounts that have INSERT privileges on SongGenres, so this limitation isn't a serious one. Once you start adding new genres, you're faced with the same problem as when there wasn't a Genre tables: typos. Rather than adding new genres that aren't found in the Genres table, look for similar ones (using e.g. the [Levenshtein distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634995/implementation-of-levenshtein-distance-for-mysql-fuzzy-search) or [`SOUNDS LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like)) and, if any are found, ask the user if they want to replace the genre with one of what was found or keep the original genre (and add it to the genre list).

Here's what the data would look like in the first case (two tables, `Songs` and `SongGenres`):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Songs;
+----+---------------------+--------+----
| id | title               | artist | ...
+----+---------------------+--------+----
|  1 | Cross Road Blues    |  ...
|  2 | Peace In the Valley |  ...   
+----+---------------------+--------+----
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM SongGenres;
+------+-------------+
| song | genre       |
+------+-------------+
|    2 | acid        |
|    1 | blues       |
|    2 | country     |
|    1 | delta blues |
|    2 | gospel      |
|    2 | house       |
|    2 | techno      |
+------+-------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT s.title, sg.genre FROM Songs AS s JOIN SongGenres AS sg ON s.id=sg.song;
+---------------------+-------------+
| title               | genre       |
+---------------------+-------------+
| Cross Road Blues    | blues       |
| Cross Road Blues    | delta blues |
| Peace In the Valley | acid        |
| Peace In the Valley | country     |
| Peace In the Valley | gospel      |
| Peace In the Valley | house       |
| Peace In the Valley | techno      |
+---------------------+-------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

With a separate Genres table, the data in Songs would look the same, but in the other tables  we'd have something like:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Genres;
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | acid        |
|  2 | blues       |
|  3 | classical   |
|  4 | country     |
|  5 | delta blues |
|  6 | folk        |
|  7 | gospel      |
|  8 | hip-hop     |
|  9 | house       |
...
| 18 | techno      |
+----+-------------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM SongGenres;
+------+-------+
| song | genre |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     2 |
|    1 |     5 |
|    2 |     1 |
|    2 |     4 |
|    2 |     7 |
|    2 |     9 |
|    2 |    18 |
+------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT s.title, g.name AS genre
    ->   FROM Songs AS s 
    ->     JOIN SongGenres AS sg ON s.id=sg.song 
    ->     JOIN Genres AS g ON sg.genre=g.id;
+---------------------+-------------+
| title               | genre       |
+---------------------+-------------+
| Cross Road Blues    | blues       |
| Cross Road Blues    | delta blues |
| Peace In the Valley | acid        |
| Peace In the Valley | country     |
| Peace In the Valley | gospel      |
| Peace In the Valley | house       |
| Peace In the Valley | techno      |
+---------------------+-------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives! In your alternative method with two separate tables, how would I assign multiple genres to a single song? Also, if you don't mind, can you please explain what "ON DELETE CASCADE" means?

Comment: By the method with two separate tables, are you referring to the one with two tables `Songs` and `SongGenres` (for a total of 2), or the one with two additional tables `SongGenres` and `Genres` (for a total of 3)? In either case, the answer is the same: each genre assigned to a song will be a row in the `SongGenres` table.

Comment: As for `ON DELETE CASCADE`, the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) explains it: "The action InnoDB takes for any UPDATE or DELETE operation that attempts to update or delete a candidate key value in the parent table that has some matching rows in the child table is [...] [d]elete or update the row from the parent table and automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table."

Answer (score -1):

SELECT DISTINCT genre1, genre2, genre3 FROM tabel

[Description](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/SQL-Statements/Select-Statement/How-does-DISTINCT-work-in-MySQL)

Maybe you need a better database design...
`songs | genres | [song_id|genre_id]`

Comment: In your example, how would I fetch the array and put it in the list? With the way you did it, when I fetch the array, I'll have three fields for each row, like $row['genre1'], $row['genre2'], and $row['genre3']. Like I said, I need everything in one list. Is there a way to combine them? Thanks.

Comment: That's the problem of the database design ;) Just bad database design. Create a table named genres, and then add the genre's to the other table. You can put them in one array, and sort this one.

Comment: Ah I see. So then in the songs table I would identify the genres by their ID in the songs table? So in the "genre" column, I'd have, for example, 4|6|10? Those numbers would correspond to the IDs in the genre table.

Comment: Something like that... Or maybe a third table with only song ID and genre ID... `Who voted my answer down and why?`

Comment: @dododedodoni I didn't vote it down but I think I can tell you why... it doesn't answer the question at all. You are right, the database is not well suited to doing what the question asks, but that doesn't mean that an answer that doesn't work at all is going to be helpful.