# Bigint vs nvarchar non-clustered index: SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have an extremely large table on which most queries use a WHERE clause to filter a column containing an ID number. Unfortunately, this ID number is stored as nvarchar(255). Will re-casting as bigint (it will not fit as int) help query performance?

Note - this ID value is not unique so a primary key cannot be assigned. Does this mean I cannot use a clustered index here? The table currently contains 0 clustered indexes.

Comment: What do you mean by "re-casting as bigint"? At run time or (hopefully...) by changing the table definition?

Comment: If a field is only ever going to contain a numeric value, **yes**, change the table definition to make that field the appropriate numeric type. You should always [choose the correct data type for your fields](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: Martin Smith, I mean changing the table definition and updating all existing values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course a `bigint`, which occupies 8 bytes, will be much faster than your `nvarchar(255)`, which may occupy up to 512 bytes if you use all 255 characters. As per Martin's comment, if this ID nowadays fits in a `bigint`, it means it has no more than 19 digits (I guess you don't have negative IDs), so it may actually occupy up to 40 bytes (2 + 2 * 19). More about this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms176089.aspx).

You can create indexes on fields which are not unique, even a clustered one. Regarding this, you may probably find this question useful: [Do clustered indexes have to be unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332982/do-clustered-indexes-have-to-be-unique)

Comment: `nvarchar(255)` occupies *up to*  512 bytes. The most that would actually be taken up storing a `bigint` type value is `2 + DATALENGTH(N'-9223372036854775808')`  which is `42`