# improve query performance on SQL Server table contain 3.5 Million rows and growing

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, database-design, query-performance

I have written one application in C# which is connected to sql server database express edition, from front end I populate the particular table in database every few second and  insert approx 200~300 Rows in this table.

Currently table contains approx 3.5 Million rows and its keep growing, the table definition is as below

```
[DEVICE_ID] [decimal](19, 5) NULL,
[METER_ID] [decimal](19, 5)  NULL,
[DATE_TIME] [decimal](19, 5)  NULL,
[COL1] [decimal](19, 5)  NULL,
[COL2] [decimal](19, 5)  NULL,
.
.
.
.
[COL25] [decimal](19, 5) NULL
```

I have created non clustered index on Date_Time column, and to note there is no unique column exists if it requires I can create identity column (Auto increment) to this but my report generation logic is totally based on Date_Time column.

I usually fire the query based on time, I.e. if I need to calculate the variation occurred in the col1 in the month period. I will need the value of Col1 on first value of 1st day and last value of last day of month, like wise i need to fire the query for flexible dates and I usually need only opening value and closing value based on Date_Time column for any chosen column.

To get first value of col1 for the first day, the query is

```
select top (1) COL1 from VALUEDATA where DeviceId=@DId and MeterId =@MId and Date_Time between @StartDateTime and @EndDateTime order by Date_Time
```

To get last value of col1 for the last day, the query is

```
select top (1) COL1 from VALUEDATA where DeviceId=@DId and MeterId =@MId and Date_Time between @StartDateTime and @EndDateTime order by Date_Time desc
```

But when I fire the above queries its takes approx 20~30 seconds, I believe this can be further optimized but don't know the way ahead.

One thought i given to this is to create another table and insert first and last row on every day basis and fetch data from this. But I will avoid the same if I can do something in existing table and query.

It’s greatly appreciable if someone can provide the inputs for the same.

Comment: Why all data types are `decimal(19,5)`? Especially for `Date_Time` this is bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fully optimize those queries you need two different multiple indexes :

```
CREATE INDEX ix_valuedata_asc ON VALUEDATA (DeviceId, MeterId, Date_Time);
CREATE INDEX ix_valuedata_des ON VALUEDATA (DeviceId, MeterId, Date_Time DESC);
```

Comment: I would test first, but I suspect the second index would only provide minimal gain, if any.

Comment: First indexing make sense,  let me test.

Comment: Your second query would prefer the descending index. But yes, the gain would be quite small.

Comment: @MarcGuillot, only the first index is needed since SQL Server can perform an ordered backwards scan after the seek on the equality predicate.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know SQL Server can go over an index backwards.

Comment: @MarcGuillot Thanks, I was testing it since last 2 days and  Its has improved the performance of my queries considerably!

Comment: I am not sure whether `Date_Time` must be last or first field in the index. It depends on the number of `DeviceId`s and `Date_Time`s.

Answer (score 1):

I have another suggestion: if your goal is to get the values of COL1, COL2 etc after you do the index lookup, the solution with just a nonclustered index on the filtering columns still has to join back to the main table, ie; do a [bookmark / RID lookup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/06/30/bookmark-lookup/).

Your info gives me the impression your base table does is not clustered (has no clustered index); is in fact a [heap table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213609.aspx)

If most of your querys on the table *follow the pattern you describe*, I would make this table [clustered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186342(v=sql.110).aspx). In contrary what most people think, you do not have to define an clustered index as the (unique) primary key. If you define a clustered index in SQL server on non unique data, SQL server will make it unique *'under water'* by adding an [invisible row identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332982/do-clustered-indexes-have-to-be-unique)...

If the main, most often **USED** selection / filter criteria on this table is date time, I would change the table to the following clustered structure:

1. First, remove all **non clustered** indexes
2. Then add the following **clustered** index:

`CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX clix_valuedata ON VALUEDATA (Date_Time, DeviceId, MeterId);`

When using query's that follow your pattern, you *(probably!)* will get very performant **Clustered index SEEK** style access to your table if you look at the **query explain plan.**. You will now get all the other columns in the table **for free**, as bookmark lookups are not needed anymore. This approach will probably **scale** better too as the table grows; because of the SEEK behaviour...