# SQL Server: Can a Clustered, Non-Unique Index Improve Performance if I'm always reading "clustered" rows?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a table [groupmembers] with three columns:

```
[dn] NVARCHAR(255)
[objectGUID] NVARCHAR(38)
[member] NVARCHAR(255)
```

The source of the data is a table where values are stored like such:

```
<dn>,<objectGUID>,<member|member|member|member|member>
```

I have an SSIS package which splits out each of the delimited values for [member] and writes a new row for each member, but keeping the same [dn] and [objectGUID].

So, all of the rows containing the members of each [dn]:[objectGUID] pair will always be written sequentially. The table will be truncated every time it is loaded.

The [dn] and [objectGUID] are different unique values representing the same source object.  I have them both because two different applications will each use one to query for [member].  Furthermore, the queries against [dn] OR [objectGUID] will (nearly) always return every associated [member].

Due to the fact that the [members] will (nearly) always be returned together, would it make sense to create a clustered index on one of [dn] or [objectGUID]?

My assumption is that if the rows are written together, clustered with their like values, and read together, that the performance would be better than with a non-clustered index.

Comment: clustered non unique  index  behaves like a clustered index with uniqueness.SQL adds [uniqueifier to make it unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332982/do-clustered-indexes-have-to-be-unique)

Comment: Your next part of question is not clear to me atleast

Answer (score 0):

To me it makes sense to put the CI on dn,objectGUID.