# WHERE clause on a clustered index AND a non-clustered index

Tags: sql-server

I have a `WHERE` clause with conditions on two columns:

```
WHERE A = 1 AND B = 2
```

Column A is a clustered index whereas column B is a non-clustered index.

My question is - are there any benefits in having a non-clustered index on column B in this specific query?

Comment: You can force specific index in the query and compare actual execution plans for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case 0 or one records is always returned because the cluster index, by default, is unique although [it is not required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4333037/1260204). If the clustered index is unique it does not matter if column B has an index or not, it won't be used in this queries execution plan. Otherwise the index *could* be used depending on the statistics.

You can verify this by reading the execution plan.

Comment: Clustered indexes can be non-unique.  A hidden “uniqifier” will be added for duplicate values of the index key columns.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Will the non clustered index be even used in case the where clause is of the form : Where A > 1 and B < 100. Considering A is clustered and B is non clustered.

Comment: @ashraydimri - That depends on the table and index statistics and then what query plan is chosen based on those statistics and the incoming statement and parameters.