# Order MySQL data by row value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that looks like this:

Table: items

```
id | itemId
---|------
0  | 1
1  | 2
2  | 3
```

Table: item_specs

```
id | itemId | key          | values
---|--------|---------------
0  | 1      | itemreceived | 2012-06-01
1  | 1      | modelyear    | 1992
2  | 1      | model        | 2
3  | 2      | itemreceived | 2012-06-05
4  | 2      | modelyear    | 2003
5  | 2      | model        | 1
6  | 3      | itemreceived | 2012-07-05
7  | 3      | modelyear    | 2000
8  | 3      | model        | 3
```

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT items.*, item_specs.* FROM item_specs
INNER JOIN item_specs ON items.itemId = item_specs.itemId
WHERE itemId IN(1,2,3)
```

How can I order the result by a key value, for example: model?

The result I'm looking for is something like this: (if I order by model)

```
id | itemId | key          | values
---|--------|---------------
3  | 2      | itemreceived | 2012-06-05
4  | 2      | modelyear    | 2003
5  | 2      | model        | 1
0  | 1      | itemreceived | 2012-06-01
1  | 1      | modelyear    | 1992
2  | 1      | model        | 2
6  | 3      | itemreceived | 2012-07-05
7  | 3      | modelyear    | 2000
8  | 3      | model        | 3
```

The content that is returned is ordered by the value that is that has the key model

Comment: Do you mean `ORDER BY key, value`

Comment: This should be easy, but you need to clarify exactly what you want. Show the result you are looking for given the table you have above. Do you want to filter the table? Sort the table? Filter and sort the table?

Comment: @Patrik We encourage individual questions to have separate question entries. Yuor second question isn't really a StackOverflow type question, However, see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11035969/1132642 (It's called an Entity Attribute Value model)

Comment: @DavidManheim Ah thank you. Yes I am aware of that. Thought I just sneak that in there.

Comment: The rows in the result do not match with rows in the table. Where did that `id=6` come from, for example?

Comment: I'm currently updating the question. I will update in a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the model number for every row. You can do that with a join:

```
SELECT items.*, item_specs.* 
FROM item_specs
INNER JOIN item_specs ON items.itemId = item_specs.itemId
INNER JOIN item_specs aux ON (aux.key = 'model' and aux.itemID = item_specs.itemId)
WHERE item_specs.itemId IN(1,2,3)
ORDER BY aux.values/*this is the model*/, item_specs.id;
```

or with a subselect:

```
SELECT items.*, 
       item_specs.*, 
       (select aux.values 
        from item_specs aux 
        where aux.key = 'model' and aux.itemID = item_specs.itemId
        ) as model
FROM item_specs
INNER JOIN item_specs ON items.itemId = item_specs.itemId
WHERE item_specs.itemId IN(1,2,3)
ORDER BY model, item_specs.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `key` = 'model' ORDER BY `values` ASC
```

You have to manually specify a table type/storage engine. That can't be seen in the structure you provided.
Read more [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/understand-mysql-table-types-innodb-myisam.aspx).

Comment: I have updated the question a bit. I want to sort by the value that belongs to the key model

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to use an order by clause. This will order by the columns you need. You can also do sneaky things here, like insert a true/false value for what you order by first.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
   Order by (case When Key='model' then 0 else 1 end), values
```

See, for instance, http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/17/sql-server-case-statement-in-order-by-clause-order-by-using-variable/

Comment: I think you understand me right but I have updated the question. I will take a closer look at your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `key` = 'model' 
ORDER BY `values`;
```